# Archiving the project give me the following error : The identity 'iPhone Distribution:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I moved the my project from one mac to another new one , i tried to built the project and there is no errors appear , when i tried to Archive it the following error appear

"The identity 'iPhone Distribution: Jeeran for Software Development' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain"

Please advice me what i can do with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming archive and building for device was working fine on your old system, the most likely explanation is that you forgot to migrate your private key from your old mac.

Open up Keychain on the old mac:

- Choose **Category: Keys** on the left pane
- Find the *key*, not *certificate* (type "private key") that you were using to codesign.
- Choose **File** | **Export Items**. Export the key as a `*.p12` file.
- Import on your new mac.

If you do it correctly, from Xcode Organizer under Provisioning Profiles you should not see any warnings.

**EDIT**

- This issue is very common: documented at the top of [Xcode FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/)
- Everything you need to know is in the [iOS Code Signing Setup, Process, and Troubleshooting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html) technote
- Including what to do if you no longer have access: [How do I delete/revoke my certificates and start over fresh?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html)

Comment: is there is away to generate new key from the new mac ?

Comment: Only by registering a new Apple developer account.

Comment: Can i download this file from the apple , note that the old mac Apple id is different than the one i use now?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the answer is no. Thats why Apple tells developers backup their *.p12 files as soon as they create developer keys.

Comment: Edit with links to additional resources, including how to start over fresh.

Comment: Thanks very much ,I exported the keys from the previous Mac and install it into the new one ,it works now